# Plotting the weekly average profit from a large POS Data set

Tags: rstudio

I am new in RStudio. I have a data frame of POS data of one month and I need to come up with an analytical report. I want to find the weekly average profit from this data set. I have tried many sources but yet to find the correct answer.

```
POS <- read.csv("POS_Data.csv")
POS$Week <- as.Date(cut(POS$Date,breaks = "week",start.on.monday = FALSE))
```

I get this error:

> Error in cut.default(POS$Date, breaks = "week", start.on.monday = FALSE) : 
>     'x' must be numeric

My data set looks like this:

[image]

Kindly go through the image. The dates are listed in descending order and the profit is represented in the last column.

Comment: I recommend changing your username - presently you are in a mindset of helplessness, which is not healthy for an engineer. Please paste into the question your best attempt so far, even though it does not work.

Comment: @halfer I will keep that in mind and change my name. I am sorry. I have edited my question and added two lines of code. I am trying to get weekly data so that I can find an average of those data. I don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you run `class(POS$Date)`? Usually when I have dates in R they are in the format "2019-02-28 11:53:33", with the dashes in between. Perhaps your variable is stored as a character and this is causing the error. If that's the case, you might be able to reload your data from the source and specify that the first column is a date.

I tried to add this as a comment but I'm pretty new too and stack overflow said I didn't have enough reputation points to do that. Hope this might help!